# Print common letters from two string by calling only one print

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

This the question: Make a function that takes two strings as input, and print the common letters that they share.
The printed letters should: - be lowercase - be in alphabetical order - appear as a single string. Please see the example to see the format of the string - There should only be letters in your result, no whitespace, numbers or special characters and if no common letter is found print no common letters.

Example usage:
task("House","computers") should print e, o, s and u exactly. If it prints eosu then that would be incorrect.
task("Hi","there") should print h
task("Foo","bar") should print no common letters
There should only be one call to print.

This is the problem I'm encountering: The below code when run prints no common letters but I used to get feedback from a bot that the task should print (and not return) a string. Please just use one print statement. E.g: task('I like big cups!','and I cannot lie!') should call print('c, e, i and l). Please help me check whether there is an arrangement problem or help me modify the code.

```
badchars = ['$','@','%',';',':','!',"*"," ",'1',"2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0",'^','&','#','~','?','[]','{',']',"+",'=','-','_','-',",",'"',"'",'`',"|","\\",'(',')']

def task(str1, str2):
    str1=str1.casefold()
    str2=str2.casefold()

    for letter in badchars:
        str1=str1.replace(letter,"")
        str2=str2.replace(letter,"")

    common =(list(set(letter for letter in str1 if letter in str2)))
    letter=len(common)
      
    if letter>1:
        common.insert(-1,"and")
    common= ','.join(common)
    common = common.replace(',and,', ' and ')
    if letter==0:
        common='no common letters'
        
    print(f'{common}')
        
task("foo", "bar")
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to clarify your specific problem? How does the current behaviour deviate from your expected?

Comment: Simpler way to get the common letters: `common = set(str1).intersection(str2)`

Comment: Change `print` to `return`.